# "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" retuned from Laravel 5.2 update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException retuned when updating a form in Laravel 5.2. I understand there could be an issue with the put method.

The form sending from the index:

```
{!! Form::model('Customers', ['route'=>['products.update', Auth::user()->id]]) !!}

{{ Form::hidden('business', Auth::user()->name, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '','maxlength'=>'255'))}}


{{ Form::label('post', 'Mailbox')}}
{{ Form::checkbox('post',1, null, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
```

The Controller is:

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
       $this->validate($request, array (
            'post' => '',
            'mailbox' => '',
            'conum' => '',
            'prefix' => '',
            'telans' => '',
            'TC' => 'required',

        ));

        //store
        $post = Customers::find($id);



        $post->post = $request->input('post');
        $post->postpro = $request->input('mailbox');
        $post->telans = $request->input('telans');
        $post->conum = $request->input('conum');
        $post->prefix = $request->inut('prefix');
        $post->tc = $request->input('TC');

        //save
        $post->save();

        //session flash message
        //Session::flash('success','This customer has now been added');

        //redirect
return redirect('/home');}
```

And the route is as follows:

```
  Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you running on an IIS server?

Comment: Running on Mamp so Apache

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` command and check if `products.update` is in the list.

Comment: It is on the list. The method is PUT @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: Is the form generate a put form ?

Comment: I tried adding the _method as put but was stilling problems @SofieneDjebali

Comment: @SofieneDjebali The error being:
ErrorException in ProductsController.php line 126:
Use of undefined constant post - assumed 'post'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forgot the quotes, replace this :

**PHP**

```
$post->post = $request->input(post);
```

with this :

```
$post->post = $request->input('post');
```

do not forget to set the _method as put.

Comment: {!! Form::model('Customers', ['route'=>['products.update', Auth::user()->id],'method' => 'PUT']) !!}

Has been added.

Now the error with your changes is:
Creating default object from empty value

Comment: Is that working ? puting quote should solve the error :ErrorException in ProductsController.php line 126: Use of undefined constant post - assumed 'post'

Comment: I am now getting the error:
 Creating default object from empty value

Comment: It's an other error :) can you edit your post and show us your entire function update, i will try to fix the bugs :)

Comment: Thank you! I have added it to the above

Comment: Try to change this : {{ Form::checkbox('post',1, null, array('class' => 'form-control'))}} with this : {{ Form::checkbox('post',1, 0, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
Is it working ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112583/discussion-between-sofiene-djebali-and-james-parsons).

Comment: Sorry @SofieneDjebali have had to leave my computer. Will check and get back to you. You have been great though!